# "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." after switching wordpress to https

Tags: wordpress

I kept getting a 'you're offline' kind of error when I tried to edit & post news to my wordpress website. I searched for a fix and I went in the settings, changing my site's url to have a https:// extension.

I reloaded everything, the main website works well, however after I log in with my credentials under /wp-admin, I get a 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.' trying to access my admin dashboard.

Comment: Are the Values also updated in the options Table? Check "siteurl" and "home"

Answer (score 0):

Try using default settings for link settings in wordpress.

Comment: I can't access the admin dashboard to change those settings.

Comment: My friend, try using database directly to change these settings.

Comment: I didn't think of that, to be honest it's the first time I'm trying my hand at wordpress.
Found an article to help me edit it with mysql through terminal, link below.
I can access my dashboard now, though my initial issue is still present so I'll try to have a go at it.
https://precisionsec.com/changing-the-wordpress-site-url-using-the-mysql-command-line/

Comment: It's good to hear it worked. Another soul has been saved. I wish you all the best :)